# how to get time as Nsdate format in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

hello I want to ask one thing I have NSString  as time and i want to convert this string in NSDate time  I have do this but I don't know what I got........

```
     NSString *Time=@"17:00:00";

     NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter3 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter3 setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    [dateFormatter3 setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
    NSDate *date1 = [dateFormatter3 dateFromString:Time];
    NSLog(@"date1 : %@", date1);
```

**OUTPUT** : *date1 : 2000-01-01 11:30:00 +0000*
I want only correct time 17:00:00 as NSDate format ...How Can get this? ....
Please solve this Problem....!!!

Comment: date1 : 2000-01-01 17:00:00 +0000   I got this out put But I want only   17:00:00 this  possible and how ?

Comment: When you log date using NSLog, it logs as what you got as output.

Comment: Do as what manujmv suggested.

Answer (score 5):

Set time zone you get proper output try this code,

```
NSString *Time=@"17:00:00";

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter3 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter3 setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];
[dateFormatter3 setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
[dateFormatter3 setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *date1 = [dateFormatter3 dateFromString:Time];
NSLog(@"date1 : %@", date1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] 
                 initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
NSString *etaStr = @"17:00:00";
    NSDate *generatedDate = [formatter dateFromString:etaStr];
NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromDate:generatedDate]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    formatter.dateFormat = @"HH:mm:ss";
    NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]); // 07:23:38

    NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:@"17:00:00"]; // 2000-01-01 15:00:00 +0000
    NSLog(@"%@", date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
NSString *Time=@"17:00:00";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter3 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter3 setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *date1 = [dateFormatter3 dateFromString:Time];
NSLog(@"date1 : %@", date1);
```

Or use these functions,

```
#define DATE_COMPONENTS (NSYearCalendarUnit| NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSWeekCalendarUnit |  NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayOrdinalCalendarUnit)

 +(NSDateComponents *)componentsForDate:(NSDate *)date 
{
    if (date!=nil)
    {
    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]
                             initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

    NSDateComponents *dayComponents =
    [gregorian components:DATE_COMPONENTS fromDate:date];

    return dayComponents;
    }

    return nil;
}

+(NSString *)timeFromNSDate:(NSDate *)date
{
    int hour=[self componentsForDate:date].hour;
    int minute=[self componentsForDate:date].minute;
    int second=[self componentsForDate:date].second;

    NSString *returnDateString= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:%d:%d",hour, minute,second];
    return returnDateString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you get in your log is probably the correct date. NSLog – exactly: -description (NSDate) – prints out the date in UTC.

[Unexpected value from NSDate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17294289/unexpected-value-from-nsdate/17296378#17296378)

BTW: You should set the date style to none.

Answer (score 0):

This is because **NSDate** is a combination of Date and Time. When you print any NSDate, it will print in this format. But an NSString from this NSDate display what you really want. So just fetch **NSString** from your date as

```
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter3 stringFromDate:date1];
 NSLog(@"date : %@ , date string : %@", date1, [dateFormatter3 stringFromDate:date1]);
```