# Handling Day light time difference

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, dst, nsdatecomponents

As per our application specification, we need to schedule call for conference, while I scheduling I have been facing problem with Day light time difference.

This is the case: US day light time changes on Nov 3 this year, when I schedule a call for eg: 5 P.M on Nov 4, that time I am converting into GMT and send to server. If I convert that GMT time its giving 4 P.M Nov 4, instead of 5 P.M. Even though its correct only, however as per user perspective he scheduled for 5 P.M not 4 P.M, so how to handle this case.

I'm converting into GMT like ...

```
- (NSDateComponents*) convert_to_gmt_time : (NSDate*) date
{
    NSDate *localDate = date;
    NSTimeInterval timeZoneOffset = [[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone] secondsFromGMT];
    NSTimeInterval gmtTimeInterval = [localDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] - timeZoneOffset;
    NSDate *gmtDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:gmtTimeInterval];

    NSDateComponents *date_comp = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components: NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit fromDate:gmtDate];

    return date_comp;
}
```

**Edit:**

This is how I'm coverting GMT time to local...

```
  NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    [gregorian setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy"];
NSDate *strt_date_loc = [gregorian dateFromComponents:start_date]; // start_date i'm filling after received from server as GMT.

    // Get date string.
    NSString *strt_date = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: strt_date_loc];
```

Any help is really appreciated. Thanx.

Comment: Server should accept and save date in UTC format. When your app get date(in UTC format) from server, you can convert it to your local time zone.

Comment: The most likely scenario here is that your input date is incorrect. Please provide the code used to generate that. :)

Comment: `strt_date_loc` is your parameter to `convert_to_gmt_time`?

Comment: @StevenFisher No, its already converted from gmt to local, strt_date_local I have used to form string using formatter, before Nov 3 its giving correct value, but after its creating string less than 1 hour than what it supposed to be.

Comment: There's no such thing as a local `NSDate`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the problem,

Problem was with GMT conversion, as I did consider the current time difference to GMT, and not the time difference that is in effect at the date to be converted.

This is how I fixed...

```
NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
[cal setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
NSDateComponents *date_comp = [cal components: NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit fromDate:localDate];
```

Answer (score 1):

Again and again and again and …: You cannot convert a date to a timezone. You can convert representations of dates to time zones. This does not change the date. Don't try to be more tricky than dates are.

[Unexpected value from NSDate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17294289/unexpected-value-from-nsdate/17296378#17296378)

If you have a date representation in local format (i. e. US) simply build a date from it by using a local date formatter. Then send this date to $anywhere.

On the way back read this date (not one of its representations) and build a local representation with a local formatter.

Never in the meaning of never send any local representation of a date to anywhere. GMT is a local  representation. (What does stand G for?)

Comment: "Greenwitch Mean time (GMT)" is it local representation?

Comment: Typo? Is *a* local representation? Of course, the local representation of Greenwich, a little town in England. http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenwich_(London)

Answer (score 1):

An NSDate is an absolute time, and not based upon a time zone.  So basically it is like storing the time as described at GMT.

So you just need to get a calendar whose timezone is GMT, and then get the components.

```
 NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
 [calendar setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];

 NSDateComponents *date_comp = [calendar components: NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit fromDate:gmtDate];
```