# Get formatted date as NSDate

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I've a NSDateFormatter set like this:

> YYYY/MM/dd HH:mm:ss

I can convert it from `NSDate` to `NSString` and from `NSString` to `NSDate`.
But what I want is to get the NSDate as I formatted it.
I thought about converting it to `NSString` then convert back to `NSDate` but this way is just awful, I'm sure there is a simpler way, right?

Comment: That's like saying I want an integer `123` to exist as `1-2-3`. An integer is an integer. You can't change its inherent data type representation. Same with dates.

Comment: If you want to get it as you formatted it, just leave it formatted.  If you want to parse/display it accurately, use "yyyy" instead of "YYYY".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't format an NSDate, it is an exact point in time.  If you are converting an NSDate to a string, and back to a NSDate, they will be identical

Comment: So, there is no way to get NSDate like my syntax 'YYYY/MM/dd HH:mm:ss'?

Comment: @IdanMoshe An NSDate object has no intrinsic string representation. It simply internally represents the number of milliseconds since some reference date. In order to convert that number to a nice-looking format, you need to use an NSDateFormatter.

Comment: No, there is no way. But there is a way to get such a representation of a date. See the link I posted.

Comment: An NSDate isn't stored that way, it represents a fixed point in time.  The format isn't formatting the date, it's providing information for the dateformatter on how to decode whatever you sent it and convert it to an nsdate.

Comment: If I would get a penny for each Q of this type, … I would have an expensive yacht, an expensive house and cheap girls.

Answer (score 2):

A date is *never* formatted. The string representation and only the string representation of a date is formatted.

[Unexpected value from NSDate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17294289/unexpected-value-from-nsdate/17296378#17296378)

Answer (score 1):

May be you want to write simple category to NSDate that will return right formatted string?

NSDate+formatted.h

```
@interface NSDate (formatted)

-(NSString)formatedString;

@end
```

NSDate+formatted.m

```
@implementation  NSDate (formatted)
-(NSString)formatedString
{
// your formatter code here 
}
@end
```