# NSDateComponents issue - set incorrect day

Tags: ios, objective-c

There are many issues similar to mine, but something goes wrong. Why function setDay sets to 1 day less? Where did I go wrong?

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSLog(@"today date = %@", today);
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear ) fromDate:today];
[components setDay:1];
NSLog(@"modified date = %@", [calendar dateFromComponents:components]);
```

Log:

```
today date = 2016-07-04 10:01:30 +0000
modified date = 2016-06-30 21:00:00 +0000
```

Modified date should be **2016-07-01**

Comment: I think its actually 2016-07-01 but at midnight

Comment: Your time zone is UTC+3, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely it *is* 2016-07-01, 24:00 GMT. `NSLog()` prints it out for GMT, not your locale time.

See here: [Unexpected value from NSDate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17294289/unexpected-value-from-nsdate/17296378#17296378)

Comment: Thank you, it solve my problem - [calendar setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];

Answer (score 1):

You should add NSCalendarUnitHour in NSDateComponents like this then then you get correct date

```
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear |NSCalendarUnitHour) fromDate:today];
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it solves my problem

Comment: @АлексейАлыбин accept my answer and upvote me

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
NSDateFormatter* df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];    
[df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];    // your time 00:00:00
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSLog(@"modified date = %@", [df stringFromDate:[calendar dateFromComponents:components]]);  // Date format NSString
```