# How can I get last 10 days from healthkit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nspredicate, healthkit

I'm reading health values of my iPhone from my objective c app.
I need only read the last 10 days, but I can't do a query to do this.

I'm trying add into a predicate the query with this code:

```
NSPredicate *explicitforDay =
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K >= %@ AND %K <= %@",
 HKPredicateKeyPathDateComponents, startDateComponents,
 HKPredicateKeyPathDateComponents, endDateComponents];
```

And then I tried this:

```
NSPredicate *explicitforDay = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ < %%@ AND %@ >= %%@", HKPredicateKeyPathStartDate
                                                                    , HKPredicateKeyPathEndDate], myFirstDate, myEndDate];
```

But in output I can see some like this:

> (startDate < CAST(529279732.871222, "NSDate") AND endDate >=
>   CAST(527983732.871222, "NSDate"))

Why are printing a CAST and wrong date values?
Thanks!

Comment: I neither see any print command in your code nor the actual values of the dates. Therefore it is hard to say, whether the print out is correct.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4 solution:**

in my example i use the convenience method `HKQuery.predicateForSamples`, this is a predicate for samples whose start and end dates fall within the specified time interval.

You need to read the last 10
Here's how to get a date -10 days from now `Date()`

*For -10 pervious days*

startDate is:  `Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -10, to: Date())!`

**Note**: You can use date from which you want next and previous days date, just change `Date(`).

endDate is : `Date()` --> (the current date)

So my predicate looks like with a specified time interval.

```
 let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(
                     withStart: startDate.beginningOfDay(), 
                     end: endDate, 
                     options: [.strictStartDate,.strictEndDate])
```

as u can see in my predicate I'm adding `beginningOfDay()` method this will allow me to start the date from 00:00

**`beginningOfDay()` method description :**

```
func beginningOfDay() -> Date {
        let beginningOfDay = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: self)
        return beginningOfDay
    }
```

you can also create a predicate format string to create equivalent predicates as describe in [heathkitDoc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkquery/1614771-predicateforsamples).

```
let explicitTimeInterval = NSPredicate(format: "%K >= %@ AND %K < %@",
                                       HKPredicateKeyPathEndDate, myStartDate,
                                       HKPredicateKeyPathStartDate, myEndDate)
```

Hopefully, will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

A date is simple a number. I've posted a longer explanation for this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17294289/unexpected-value-from-nsdate/17296378#17296378).

So a simple number is put into the statement. It is the numerical representation of your date. To treat the number as date, it is casted to the given type `"NSDATE"`.